# ASP.NET Core 2 Web API models

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I can't find any documentation other than this tutorial from windows on how to create a model: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api

So far everything's good for ASP.NET core basics, but my models are a bit more complex than the one in the tutorial and I can't seem to find any doc online for my problem.

My models looks like this:

```
public class Set
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public byte Rep { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfDS { get; set; }
    public double PercentDrop { get; set; }
    public virtual Exercise Exercise { get; set; }
    public int ExerciseId { get; set; }
}

public class Exercise
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Set> SetList { get; set; } 
    public byte RestTime { get; set; }
    public virtual Workout Workout { get; set; }
    public int WorkoutId { get; set; }
}

public class Workout
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Exercise> ExerciseList { get; set; }
    public bool Archived { get; set; }
}
```

Then my controller looks like this:

```
namespace WorkoutKeeper.Core.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class WorkoutController : Controller
    {
        public readonly ApiContext _context;

        public WorkoutController(ApiContext context)
        {

            _context = context;

            if (_context.WorkoutItems.Count()==0)
            {
                Workout wo1 = new Workout() { Name = "WO1" };
                _context.WorkoutItems.Add(wo1);
                _context.SaveChanges();

                Exercise e1 = new Exercise() { Name = "E1", WorkoutId = wo1.Id };
                _context.ExerciseItems.Add(e1);
                _context.SaveChanges();

                Set s1 = new Set() { Rep = 10, Weight = 50, ExerciseId = e1.Id };
                _context.SetItems.Add(s1);
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Workout> GetAll()
        {
            return _context.WorkoutItems;
        }

    }
}
```

Now, if i fire it up then got to `http://localhost:55556/api/workout`, I receive an incomplete json which looks like this:

```
[
 {
  "id":1,
  "name":"WO1",
  "description":null,
  "exerciseList":
   [
    {
     "id":1,
     "name":"E1",
     "description":null,
     "setList":
      [
       {
        "id":1,
        "rep":10,
        "weight":50,
        "numberOfDS":0,
        "percentDrop":0.0
```

but when I reload the page, the json is now like this:

```
[{
  "id":1,
  "name":"WO1",
  "description":null,
  "exerciseList":null,
  "archived":false
}]
```

Now, i'm just trying to figure out a way to have a relation between the data to be able to send a complete `Workout` object by json instead of the json with `"setList":null` or the incomplete one.

Thanks!

Comment: You forgot to add the action that you are calling

Comment: You are also not assigning `context` to `_context` in your controller's constructor, so this wouldn't even work. Please post the real code

Comment: I just added the action and edited the `_context = context;`. I just forgot it when I copied my code sorry. @CamiloTerevinto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your models have a loop - `Workout` contains a list of `Exercise`, and each `Exercise` contains the `Workout` it belongs to. When the serializer tries to format your objects as JSON, it will detect this loop, and either give up and leave the property as `null`, or complain about circular referencing.

You can bypass this by using the `JsonIgnore` attribute to prevent `Exercise.Workout` from being serialized, or by using `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes to explicitly mark which fields *should* be serialized. You also will need to do the same for `Set.Exercise`.

```
public class Exercise
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Set> SetList { get; set; } 
    public byte RestTime { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Workout Workout { get; set; }
    public int WorkoutId { get; set; }
}

public class Set
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public byte Rep { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfDS { get; set; }
    public double PercentDrop { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Exercise Exercise { get; set; }
    public int ExerciseId { get; set; }
}
```